# How to map Mysql Row with Mysql Column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql table like

Subject Table

```
id|markid |name
--|-------|--------
1 |1      |subject1
2 |2      |subject2
3 |3      |subject3
4 |4      |subject4
```

Mark Table

```
id|Mark1|mark2|Mark3|mark4
--|-----|-----|-----|------ 
 1|96   |95   |96   |98
```

My Expected Result is like

```
  Mark|subject
  ----|--------
   96 |subject1
   95 |subject2
   96 |subject3
   98 |subject4
```

Comment: Normalise your mark table

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: I created an answer that shows how to normalize. But I have to ask, is it necessary for you to have marks in a separate table. Why not just put the marks in the same table as the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why your table design is like this, anyway if you just want this result, you can try following sql, may help for you;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29f87/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Subject 
    (`id` varchar(2), `markid` varchar(7), `name` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO Subject 
    (`id`, `markid`, `name`)
VALUES
    ('1', '1', 'subject1'),
    ('2', '2', 'subject2'),
    ('3', '3', 'subject3'),
    ('4', '4', 'subject4')
;


CREATE TABLE Mark 
    (`id` varchar(2), `Mark1` varchar(5), `mark2` varchar(5), `Mark3` varchar(5), `mark4` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO Mark 
    (`id`, `Mark1`, `mark2`, `Mark3`, `mark4`)
VALUES
    ('1', '96', '95', '96', '98')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
   CASE markid WHEN 1 THEN Mark1
               WHEN 2 THEN Mark2
               WHEN 3 THEN Mark3
               WHEN 4 THEN Mark4 END AS Mark,
   name AS subject
FROM Subject
LEFT JOIN Mark ON Mark.id = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29f87/3/0)**:

```
| Mark |     name |
|------|----------|
|   96 | subject1 |
|   95 | subject2 |
|   96 | subject3 |
|   98 | subject4 |
```

Comment: Why do a select for each mark? You could just join the mark table on id=1 and reference the appropriate mark column from the joined table. Like this : `SELECT CASE markid 
 WHEN 1 THEN Mark1
 WHEN 2 THEN Mark2
 WHEN 3 THEN Mark3
 WHEN 4 THEN Mark4
END AS Mark, name AS subject FROM subject LEFT JOIN Mark ON Mark.id=markid`